# Read/Write Snapshots in Azure/AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

We're trying to get information about Azure and/or AWS in terms of their ability to create snapshots of data drives that are writable and can be attached to VMs.

Currently we use a model with our test environments on-prem, where we have a clone of a set of production databases/logs on drives that are quite large (+2TB) on our EMC SAN.  Instead of making full copies of the clone for each test environment DB server, we use EMC VNX redirect-on-write snapshots.  This allows us to quickly provision the DB server VM in the test environment without having to make a full copy of the DB/logs, and saves on SAN space, as only the delta from new writes to the snapshot are stored as new data.  This works really well as we only need one full copy of the source DBs/logs.

Does anyone know if Azure or AWS has the ability to do something similar or a reasonable alternative?  Making full copies of the databases/logs for each test environment is not really an option for us.  We started looking at the Azure SQL Database copy feature but we were not sure if this creates a full copies or writable snapshots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EBS Snapshots are uploaded in deltas, the first snapshot is a full backup obviously

Comment: Could you check if this doc for Azure satisfies your requirement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-incremental-snapshots

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if Azure or AWS has the ability to do something similar or a reasonable alternative?

Azure VM Disk uses Azure Page Blob to store data. Until now, the snapshot of a Azure blob can be read, copied, or deleted, but **not modified**.

I am sorry to tell that Azure doesn't provide the similar thing to fit your requirement. In Azure, we do need to use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) to copy the whole blob to make the new blob writable.